# How to get people to notice I added a comment which is a follow-up question

Tags: support, asking-questions, comment-replies

I recently asked a [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/11542/combinatorial-group-theory-lyndon-schupp-lemma-4-7-automorphisms-of-free-gr) about the beginning of a proof in a book.

Artudo Magidin helped me greatly, but it took me 2 days until I understood the answer and could accept it. Now I have another question about the end of the same proof. I left it as a comment there. Will he notice it? What is the appropriate thing to do to make him or someone else notice this new comment which is in some way a follow up question?

(I can post it as a new question, but since it's about the same proof, I'm not sure if this is the appropriate thing to do on math.stackexchange).

Comment: Since you commented on an answer he wrote, he already received a notification of it.  In general (e.g. if you want to respond to someone else's comment) use the @ symbol together with their username (I think you can take the part of their username before the first space).  This will cause a notification to pop up.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan: Thank you. I want him to notice the latest comment on my original question, and not the one on his answer. He used @user3533 earlier and I didn't notice a notification. Where do they show?

Comment: The orange envelope on the top.  I don't think you are a registered user, which is probably why you aren't receiving notifications.

Comment: The "StackExchange" dropdown at the upper left corner of the site ought to have a red circle with the number of unread comments/answers for you. Otherwise, there's the envelope...

Comment: @Qiaochu: S/he's registered; s/he didn't fill in a username though so the name looks generic.

Comment: I see.  Does the notification function work if you don't fill in a username?  I can't find user3533 via a user search.

Comment: Next time someone answers me with "@user3533" I'll answer that.

Comment: I infer from Jeff's answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65006) that you can't be notified if you're nameless.

Comment: By the way, iirc, you need only use enough of the username to uniquely match the most recent posts (but at least 3 chars), e.g. @use, or @Qia to notify the authors of the 2nd and 3rd most recent posts above. Qiaochu: did it notify you?

Comment: Confirmed, you can get notices if you are unregistered. Before I registered, I used to get these notices all the time.

Comment: Editing the question to include the next part of your question will increase the visibility to others by bringing it to the top of the first page.

Comment: @user3533: Did it work?

Comment: @Charles: I get notifications, but it turns out that I was registered to begin with so it's not very surprising.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: If I want multiple persons get notified, then?

Answer (score 4):

A few changes since this was asked

1. It is no longer possible to be nameless; you will be named user12345 at a minimum.
2. Click the help link next to the comment submit button to see basic help, which includes notification info.

   [image: commenting help]
3. Comment syntax is also documented on https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help